# Save mp3 from HTTP server with BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0 and play file

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

Apologies, I am very new to BlackBerry development. All I need to do is save an mp3 file (which I download from a HTTP server), and then play it back. I have most of the code done, but I keep getting a file system error 1003. *(I have to use BlackBerry JDE 4.5.0)*.

```
try {
    FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open( "file://data/myfile.mp3", Connector.READ_WRITE );
    final HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://som.server.com/andFile.mp3;interface=wifi");

    if (!fconn.exists()) {
        fconn.create();
    } else {
        fconn.delete();
        fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open( "file://data/myfile.mp3", Connector.READ_WRITE );
        fconn.create();
    }

    final InputStream inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
    final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        int ch;
        while ( ( ch = inputStream.read() ) != -1 ) {
            buffer.append( (char) ch );
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
        connection.close();
    }

    fconn.setWritable(true);

    final OutputStream outputStream = fconn.openOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(buffer.toString().getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}


final Player mPlayer;
final VolumeControl vc;
final InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("data/myfile.mp3");

try {
    mPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/mpeg");
    mPlayer.addPlayerListener(WelcomeScreen.this);
    mPlayer.realize();
    mPlayer.prefetch();

    vc = (VolumeControl) mPlayer.getControl("VolumeControl");
    vc.setLevel(50);

    mPlayer.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

In the above code I just try to play the file I save, but it I get the file system error. I did check on the device, and it seems that the file was actually properly saved once.

What is the correct path that I should use to save files under the application data folder?